# OR Software Forums

Tags: software

A list of OR Software forums would be nice.

Can someone import the list of OR Software forums from the (now) read-only OR Exchange at https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/9068/or-software-forums ?

Can you please delete extinct software, add additional software, and update links to be current?

Comment: Should be moved to our Meta, as a FAQ.

Comment: @Rob I disagree. Regular people looking for info on SE don't look at meta. As far as i know, it would not show up using the search box on or.stackexchange.com . Is it possible to have FAQ on the main OR SE site?

Comment: "Regular people" should know to look to Meta, for FAQs (or perhaps this is an iFAQ). Google will find it, main - no. The other close vote is for "too broad", which I don't disagree with, mine is for 'move to Meta' (which keeps it open). On SO there are a couple of similar questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254674/is-it-possible-to-ask-about-list-of-opensource-or-commercial-libraries-in-stack and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294364/there-are-no-stack-exchange-sites-that-allow-asking-for-opensource-library-reco?rq=1 which were downvoted out of existence. We'll see.

Answer (score 27):

Here is the augmented and updated list. This should be a good starting point for further improvements.

This list is very optimization-heavy (even the automatic differentiation software is most likely to be used by O.R. people in support of nonlinear optimization). So perhaps some additions outside optimization would be warranted, as well as machine learning tools.

- ```
  **ADiMat (matrix level automatic differentiator in MATLAB)**: Mailing list at https://lists.sc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/sympa/info/adimat-users
  ```
- ```
  **AIMMS**: http://groups.google.com/group/aimms
  ```
- ```
  **ALGOPY (Automatic differentiator in Python)**:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/algopy
  ```
- **AMPL**: http://groups.google.com/group/ampl
- ```
  **CasADi**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/casadi-users
  ```
- ```
  **COIN-OR** List of mailing lists at [http://list.coin-or.org/mailman/listinfo](http://list.coin-or.org/mailman/listinfo),<br> main page at https://www.coin-or.org/
  ```
- ```
  **CPLEX**: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer?CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7  **Legacy forum** ht
  ```
- ```
  **CP Optimizer**: [IBM Forum](http://ibm.biz/ConstraintProgForums), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-optimizer)
  ```
- ```
  **CVX**: http://ask.cvxr.com/
  ```
- ```
  **CVXPY**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cvxpy
  ```
- ```
  **GAMS**: https://forum.gamsworld.org/ and http://www.gams.com/maillist/gams_l.htm
  ```
- ```
  **Gurobi**: [https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us) (before 04/2019: [Gurobi Optimization](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gurobi) @ Google Groups)
  ```
- ```
  **JuMP**: https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt
  ```
- ```
  **KNITRO**: http://groups.google.com/group/knitro
  ```
- ```
  **MANOPT (optimization on manifolds)**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/manopttoolbox
  ```
- ```
  **MATLAB**: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/index
  ```
- ```
  **MiniZinc**: https://www.minizinc.org/forum.html
  ```
- ```
  **MOSEK**: http://groups.google.com/group/mosek
  ```
- ```
  **MPT (Multiparametric Toolbox)**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mpt-user
  ```
- ```
  **NEOS**: https://neos-server.org/neos/help.html
  ```
- ```
  **OPL**: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000002053
  ```
- ```
  **OptaPlanner (Java, open source)**: [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/optaplanner-dev) - [others (issue tracker, StackOverflow, ...)](https://www.optaplanner.org/community/getHelp.html)
  ```
- ```
  **Optimization Services (COIN-OR project)**: http://groups.google.com/group/optimizationservices
  ```
- ```
  **OPTI Toolbox**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opti-toolbox-forum **Effective June 7 2019, OPTI Toolbox Development has ended and the Google group is now read only**. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opti-toolbox-forum/dR6x-1gBMkA .
  ```
- ```
  **OR-Tools:**: http://groups.google.com/group/or-tools-discuss
  ```
- ```
  **PuLP**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pulp-or-discuss
  ```
- ```
  **PYOMO**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pyomo-forum
  ```
- ```
  **Python-MIP**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/python-mip
  ```
- ```
  **QuanDec**: http://www.cassotis.com/quandec
  ```
- ```
  **SAS/OR** http://communities.sas.com/t5/Mathematical-Optimization/bd-p/operations_research
  ```
- ```
  **SCIP**: Use SCIP tag on [https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scip),<br> mailing list at https://listserv.zib.de/mailman/listinfo/scip/
  ```
- ```
  **SciPy**: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scipy-user
  ```
- ```
  **SNOPT** https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/snopt
  ```
- ```
  **Xpress** https://community.fico.com/s/optimization-user-forum
  ```
- ```
  **YALMIP**: http://groups.google.com/group/yalmip
  ```

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Can you fix the formatting? When I edited it yesterday, the formatting got screwed up. It was o.k. before I edited it. Even the older versions now have screwed up formatting, so rolling back the version didn't help. i don't know what happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

- For users of R and RStudio, there's the [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/) forum (which covers R topics, not just RStudio).
- An R user community formerly on Google+ is now the [Statistics and R Community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/statistics-and-r-community) on Google groups.